# Bug for export my project

Tags: interface, export, blend-files, project

Good morning,
One of my Blender project bug. I don’t have access to my main menu and therefore can’t export my project. Can you help me[image]?

Comment: I think you may have set the interface size too big. Place your cursor in the top row where the menu should be and CTRL + mouse wheel scroll up so the buttons move to the right

Comment: You can also hold the middle mouse button down over the menu bar and simply drag it sideways.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)